# How can I set up my default view in MVC4 to point to a specific area, controller and action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a User area and inside this I have the following registered:

```
context.MapRoute("DefaultRedirect",
    "",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);
```

When I use routeDebug it tells me that when I connect to my site www.xxx.com then it will try to call

```
area = User, controller = Account, action = Login
```

When I connect directly using: www.xxx.com/User/Account/Login my login page appears.

When I don't use routeDebug and connect to my site www.xxx.com then I get an error message saying:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /
```

Here's my controller action method:

```
   public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "xx";
            return View("~/Areas/User/Views/Account/Login.cshtml");
        }
```

I am very confused as routeDebug appears to show I am going to the right controller and action however when I don't use that and place a breakpoint it does not seem to go to the controller action.

Comment: Can you verify that ~/Areas/User/Views/Account/Login.cshtml"); exists in this loocation - that may be the error. Ive only dabbled with MVC but this should work if you simply do return View(); as that will resolve to the login view of the account controller.

Comment: It's there and it works if I directly call the action with www.xxx.com/User/Account/Login just not if I call www.xxx.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this controller is inside the same area i think you just can use

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "xx";
        return View();
    }
```

Either way if you have only the views on a different areas you can use

```
return View("~/Views/YourArea/YourController/YourView.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

Will redirect to specific controller and specific action.
If account is deeper in folders just include the path

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand your suggestion. Where are you suggesting I put this code? Thanks